# ODP.NET Managed driver with Ldap authentication

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, odp.net

I realise this question may be a bit vague, but I am a bit stuck with this problem.

I want to connect to oracle db 11.2.0.3.0 version with a managed ODP.NET driver (version 12.2.1100 from NuGet) - I am migrating a legacy app from the native driver.

The code to connect is trivial:

```
var connectionString = "Data Source=MY_TNS_ALIAS;User ID=first.last;Password=mypassword";
using (OracleConnection cn = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
{ 
    cn.Open();
}
```

but I receive an exception:
`Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException Message=ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied`

I added `TNS_ADMIN` environment variable and checked with Procmon that `tnsnames.ora` and `sqlnet.ora` are being read.

The old native driver works perfectly fine with the same code (and different imports). Additionnaly, the code works fine for Non-Ldap users (users with entry in `dba_users`)

I tried using `OracleConnectionStringBuilder`, with no success.

I also checked that if I only using LDAP in NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH the TNS alias will be queried in LDAP and `ldap.ora` is read - but it is not my goal.

My questions

1. Is LDAP authentication supported by the native driver?
2. Are there any differences between native and managed driver that must be taken into account? Any additional variables? Escaping of the dot sign in username?
3. What addtional tools can be used to debug this (I used `TraceLevel`, `TraceOption`, `TraceFileLocation`)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Mabey try the [OracleConnectionStringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/OracleConnectionStringBuilderClass.htm#ODPNT2683) class. i.e. `connectionString.Password = "...";`  and `connectionString.UserID = "...";`

Comment: Maybe you mix two different items. One is TNS alias resolution by Oracle Name server (which utilize common LDAP protocol). The other is user-authentication by Networks and LDAP Directories. TNS alias resolution seems to work since you get an error message back from database. Thus `TraceLevel` and `TraceOption` does not help. For security reasons it will be very difficult to trace any user credentials.

Comment: I updated the question with `OracleConnectionStringBuilder` approach. I realise that LDAP authentication and LDAP Tns alias resolution are 2 different things, I am only interested in the former. I see my passwd up to `OraclePoolManager.InitializeSEPSCredentials()`, but the code quickly gets messy after this point.

Comment: Did you set `SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_REQUIRED = 1`?

Comment: Added this option, with no success

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Configuring Oracle Data Provider for .NET](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/InstallConfig.htm#ODPNT8154)

> Only NTS authentication is supported. No RADIUS nor Kerberos5 authentication.

So, it depends with method you use: [Authentication by the Network](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/authmeth.htm#i1007525)

> - Authentication Using SSL
> - Authentication Using Third-Party Services
>
>   - Kerberos Authentication
>   - PKI-Based Authentication
>   - Authentication with RADIUS
>   - Directory-Based Services